# Natural rep of $ SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ and decomposing tensor powers into irreps

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$ Consider the natural representation of $ \SL(2,\mathbb{Z}) $ on $ V=\mathbb{C}^2 $.

What is the decomposition of $ V^{\otimes n} $ into irreps of $ \SL(2,\mathbb{Z}) $?

I know about the decomposition of $ (\mathbb{C}^2)^{\otimes n} $ into irreps for the natural representation of $ \SL(2,\mathbb{C}) $.

The $ \SL(2,\mathbb{Z}) $ decomposition must be at least that much, but maybe there is further branching of some $ \SL(2,\mathbb{C}) $ irreps into direct sums of $ \SL(2,\mathbb{Z}) $ irreps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just the same as for $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$. Restricting an algebraic representation of $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ to $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ preserves irreducibility. The key fact here is that $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is Zariski dense in $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: I see, so is it the case that a subspace $ W $ of $ V^{\otimes n} $ closed under the action of a discrete subgroup $ \Gamma $ of $ SL(2,\mathbb{C}) $ is automatically closed under the action of the Zariski closure of $ \Gamma $ as well?

Comment: Yes that's right, and that will be true for any algebraic representation representation of $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ not just $V^{\otimes n}$.

Comment: Although let me issue a warning:  This can fail for continuous representations of $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$, and moreover $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ has pretty complicated representation theory and most representations do not appear inside any restriction from $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$.